# AngularJS repeat duplicate error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Included is an object array being used in an ng-repeat call

[image]

And here is the error

[image]

For the love of me I cannot seem to get why angular is treating these as duplicates.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please add your ng-repeat code to this question.

Comment: Based on that error, it looks like there actually are duplicates, and the data you posted isn't the same as what's in your app, i.e. "title":"Timi Aiyemo"

Answer (score 2):

Angular is telling you it doesn't know how to differentiate the items in your list, so you must tell it which field in your objects make it unique. [Click here for more documentation on `track by`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)

To do this you need to add `track by` to your `ng-repeat` statement. You can specify any field on the object such as `yid`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.yid">
    ...
</div>
```

However, if you didn't have any fields that tracked uniqueness, you can also track by the index of the item in the list using `$index`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Sigh...feared as much. The problem is that theres a feature where users can delete a list item and track by causes the deletion experience for the user to be clunky. Thanks alot.

Comment: That seems strange since `track by` should be virtually transparent. It should just be a matter of removing the item from the list or reloading the list of items. In the case of your `yid` that should be unique, so it won't matter in either case.